# Not able to figure out a way to permanently change the nameserver 127.0.0.53 to 8.8.8.8 on reboot

Tags: 18.04

I am using ubuntu 18.04 and am a new linux user. I am to install dnsmasq and everything is fine. But when I reboot, the  /etc/resolv.conf file shows 127.0.0.53 not the nameserver I have given(8.8.8.8). I want to change this permanently. Im stuck here. Can someone please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, 127.0.0.53 shows that systemd-resolve is running. To properly set your preferred DNS nameserver, set it in Network Manager:

[image]

Restart Network Manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Confirm the correct nameserver addresses:

```
resolvectl status | grep Server
```

Ideally, you will see:

```
Current DNS Server: 8.8.8.8
       DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8
```